# SQL Server IDE that checks variable case sensitivity?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I understand that SQL Server Instance collation dictates the case sensitivity of elements in a script, such as variable names and CTEs. Is there a way to configure SQL Server Management studio to automatically detect or enforce case mismatches? If not, is there another 3rd party SQL IDE that does it?

Comment: What mismatches? Scripts have no collation, database objects do. No IDE can guess what collation you wanted, it knows what collation you specified when you created a table or column, or when you used the `COLLATE` keyword

Comment: The interface you use can't force case sensitivity (or error as a result of inconsistencies on behalf of the RDBMS). If case sensitivity is important, ensure you're using a case sensitive collation; it's as "simple" as that.